# Chat status on landing page of Apple.se ?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I see Photo.se has an entry to left side of the landing page (http://photo.stackexchange.com). I wish Apple.se also could have the same.

If I want to see about the chat room status, I have to click on a question, then only I can see the status of it !

Can we fix this ?

Comment: This is something that can probably be included in the final design of the site once we launch.

Comment: This are two completely different question, could ask another question about the chat room status?

Comment: @Dori About the chat room status.

Comment: @dori he was talking about the *left* side, so I thought it was something else besides the chat box. But I didn't understood what it could be. It makes more sense, now :)

Comment: @Dori DBA is still in beta **and** has the Chat box on the front page. But it's not (yet?) applied on our site.

Comment: @Dori, I don't know if it was included on DBA.SE. But first of all, Jeff didn't add the "status-completed" tag. So that *should* mean that they fixed it on DBA and he asked the dev team to fix it here too. But I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a mistake on DBA and has been corrected.

Comment: your answer is some what confusing to me and other mods here. I didn't see chat box appearing on Apple.se website still. Are you referring to DBA.se or normal database issue for this site ? Can you please give more info here..

Comment: @gari beta sites do not get chatrooms on the homepage.